# Update MySQL table based on select

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for me to run an update query based on a select for each row? Here's what I was thinking of trying:

```
UPDATE adverts SET advert_visits = (SELECT COUNT(earning_id) FROM earnings WHERE earning_advert_id = 1093)
```

But I'm not sure how to make the select apply the right advert_id from the adverts table for each row?

Or maybe this is just a totally invalid syntax, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply refer to updated table:

```
UPDATE adverts
SET advert_visits = (
    SELECT COUNT(earning_id)
    FROM earnings
    WHERE earning_advert_id = adverts.advert_id
)
```

Comment: I think that is just what I was looking for. Seems obvious now I think about it! I'll accept in 7mins